# Python csv writer "AttributeError: __exit__" issue

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have three variables I want to write in a tab delimited .csv, appending values each time the script iterates over a key value from the dictionary.

Currently the script calls a command, regex the stdout as `out` then assigns the three defined regex groups to individual variables for writing to .csv labeled `first` `second` and `third`. I get a __exit_ error when I run the below script.

/note I've read up on csv.writer and I'm still confused as to whether I can actually write multiple variables to a row.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
 import csv, re, subprocess

 for k in myDict:
     run_command = "".join(["./aCommand", " -r data -p ", str(k)])
     process = subprocess.Popen(run_command,
                                shell=True,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
     out, err = process.communicate()
     errcode = process.returncode
     pattern = re.compile('lastwrite|(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})|alert|trust|Value')
     grouping = re.compile('(?P<first>.+?)(\n)(?P<second>.+?)([\n]{2})(?P<rest>.+[\n])', 
                           re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)


    if pattern.findall(out):         
        match = re.search(grouping, out)
        first = match.group('first')
        second = match.group('second')
        rest = match.group('rest')

     with csv.writer(open(FILE, 'a')) as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerow(first, second, rest)
```

Edit: Requested in the comments to post entire traceback, note the line listed in traceback will not match the above code as this is not the entire script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mydir/pyrr.py", line 60, in <module>
run_rip()
File "/mydir/pyrr.py", line 55, in run_rip
with csv.writer(open('/mydir/ntuser.csv', 'a')) as f:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Answer: Using the below comment I was able to write it as follows.

```
f = csv.writer(open('/mydir/ntuser.csv', 'a'),
                       dialect=csv.excel,
                       delimiter='\t')
f.writerow((first, second, rest))
```

Comment: Post the entire traceback message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. The `with` statement takes a context manager, i.e., an object with an `__enter__` and an `__exit__` method, such as the object returned by `open`. `csv.writer` does not provide such an object. You are also attempting to create the writer twice:

```
with open(FILE, 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(first, second, rest)
```

The `with ... f:` is like a `try...except...finally` that guarantees that `f` is closed no matter what happens, except you don't have to type it out. `open(...)` returns a context manager whose `__exit__` method is called in that `finally` block you don't have to type. That is what your exception was complaining about. `open` returns an object that has `__exit__` properly defined and can therefore handle normal exit and exceptions in the `with` block. `csv.writer` does not have such a method, so you can't use it in the `with` statement itself. You have to do it in the `with` block following the statement, as I've shown you.

Comment: So to clarify are you saying I can't write to with csv.writer in a with statement since there is no f.close() functionality? Sorry I'm still pretty new to Python and programming in general. @Mad Physicist