# AttributeError Issue with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, with-statement

If I run the file that has this code, I have no problems and everything is smooth.
I'm now calling this class in another file and for some reason I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\cato\work\reports\runReports.py", line 524, in runAllAdmis
    self.sortAcctCol()
  File "C:\users\cato\work\reports\runReports.py", line 553, in sortAcctCol
    with open(self.inFile, "r") as self.oi, self.temp1:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

I don't understand why it's working in the original file and not when I call it from another. I looked up my error message and I [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497373/python-csv-writer-attributeerror-exit-issue) but when I tried configuring my code to match, I couldn't figure out how to apply it in my situation. I think this mostly due to me not understanding the actual error.

This is my code:

```
def sortAcctCol(self):

    with open(self.inFile, "r") as self.oi, self.temp1:
        r = csv.reader(self.oi)
        w = csv.writer(self.temp1)

        self.header = next(r)

        self.sortedCol = sorted(r, key=operator.itemgetter(self.acct), reverse=False)

        for row in self.sortedCol:
            w.writerow(row)

    self.temp1 = self.temp1.name
```

Comment: I would expect `with open(self.inFile, "r") as self.oi, self.temp1` to give a `NameError`. Anyway, why are you using instance attibutes as your variables in this statement?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve with this line `with open(self.inFile, "r") as self.oi, self.temp1: ` but you can not have multiple variables like that. Please see: [Multiple variables in Python 'with' statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893333/multiple-variables-in-python-with-statement) and [Specification: The 'with' Statement section of PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham can you elaborate on TemporaryFiles vis a vis multiple assignment targets in the with statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are passing a string as *self.temp1*:

```
In [3]:   with open("out.log", "r") as read, "foo.txt":
   ...:     pass
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-9088e1884eea> in <module>()
----> 1 with open("out.log", "r") as read, "foo.txt":
      2   pass
      3 

AttributeError: __exit__
```

open *self.temp1* also:

```
def sort_acct_col(self):
    with open(self, "r") as read, open(self.temp1, "w") as write:
        r = csv.reader(read)
        next(r)
        sorted_col = sorted(r, key=operator.itemgetter(self.acct), reverse=False)
        csv.writer(write).writerows(sorted_col)
```

Also I presume *self.acct* is an integer or your *itemgetter* logic won't be working.